# Cisco ASAv not building up child SA

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-ios, ipsec

**Background information**

I have a Cisco 2911 router and a Cisco ASAv connected using a IKEv2 based IPSec tunnel. The tunnel initially comes up fine as soon as there is some traffic from the routers end. The router is mobile, hence it has changing outside addresses and is always the initiator. On ASA side, the VPN peer is hence not configured, a dynamic crypto-map is used.

There are two SAs defined for the IPSec connection, the left IP is the router's side, the right IPs are ASA.

- 192.168.10.0/24 <=> xx.xx.66.0/24
- 192.168.10.0/24 <=> 192.168.255.0/24

192.168.10.0/24 is a network behind the router, while xx.xx.66.0/24 is the network behind the ASA and 192.168.255.0/24 is the IP pool for AnyConnect clients connecting to the ASA.

To fire up the tunnel as soon as the router starts and has an IP address assigned on is outside interface (Gi 0/0), the router has an NTP server configured which is in the xx.xx.66.0/24 network. This actually works fine, the IKEv2 SA is up and working, the first child SA is also up and running.

**Problem statement**

The second SA (192.168.10.0/24 <=> 192.168.255.0/24) however only works when I first initiate the SA from the routers end by sending some packets (for example with `ping 192.168.255.10 sourve vlan 10 repeat 1`, where the .10 is completely random). Then the SA is up and I can connect to the router from the AnyConnect pool. This however is not the idea of this concept, as the tunnel should be established such that the support engineers connected to the ASA via AnyConnect can access the router and troubleshoot any issues.

Looking at the debug output from `debug crypto ikev2 protocol 50`, `debug crypto ikev2 platform 50` and `debug crypto ipsec 50` does not show any hint that the ASA at least tries to build the tunnel.

**Configurations**

Here are the relevant parts of both configurations. If you are missing anything, please let me know.

Cisco 2911 Router, Running IOS 15.4(3)M3 w/ security license

```
ip cef
license boot module c2900 technology-package securityk9
!
crypto ikev2 proposal default
 encryption aes-cbc-256
 integrity sha512
 group 14
!
crypto ikev2 keyring EzVPNKeys
 peer MR-ASA
  address 146.140.xx.xx
  pre-shared-key local xxx1
  pre-shared-key remote xxx2
!
crypto ikev2 profile MobileRacks
 match identity remote address xx.xx.193.9 255.255.255.255 
 identity local key-id MobileRacks
 authentication remote pre-share
 authentication local pre-share
 keyring local EzVPNKeys
!
crypto ipsec transform-set AES256-SHA-512 esp-aes 256 esp-sha512-hmac 
 mode tunnel
!
crypto map FlexVPN 10 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer xx.xx.193.9
 set transform-set AES256-SHA-512 
 set pfs group14
 set ikev2-profile MobileRacks
 match address FlexVPN
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description outside
 ip address dhcp
 crypto map FlexVPN
!
interface Vlan10
 description management
 ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group VL10-MGMT-IN out
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp
!
ip access-list extended FlexVPN
 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 146.140.66.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.255.0 0.0.0.255
!
ntp source Vlan10
ntp server xx.xx.66.230
```

Cisco ASAv5, Runnint ASA Version 9.6(1)

```
ip local pool AnyConnectPool 192.168.255.10-192.168.255.254 mask 255.255.255.0
! Is used for AnyConnect, not shown here
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address xx.xx.193.9 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address xx.xx.66.26 255.255.255.0 
!
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
!
access-list outside_cryptomap_eventrack extended permit ip xx.xx.66.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_cryptomap_eventrack extended permit ip 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 
!
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal FhG-AES-IKEv2
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-512
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA
crypto dynamic-map ConsoleServerConnectionProfile 10 match address outside_cryptomap_eventrack
crypto dynamic-map ConsoleServerConnectionProfile 10 set pfs group14
crypto dynamic-map ConsoleServerConnectionProfile 10 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal FhG-AES-IKEv2
crypto dynamic-map ConsoleServerConnectionProfile 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto dynamic-map ConsoleServerConnectionProfile 10 set reverse-route
crypto map MapOutside 1 ipsec-isakmp dynamic ConsoleServerConnectionProfile
crypto map MapOutside 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map MapOutside interface outside
!
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha512
 group 14     
 prf sha512
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
!
group-policy IKEv2GroupPolicy internal
group-policy IKEv2GroupPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2 
!
tunnel-group MobileRacks type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group MobileRacks general-attributes
 default-group-policy IKEv2GroupPolicy
tunnel-group MobileRacks ipsec-attributes
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
```

**Additional Output**

From the ASA's perspective, IP being a DHCP assigned outside IP of the router: `show ipsec sa peer xx.xx.xx.xx detail`:

```
peer address: xx.xx.222.246
    Crypto map tag: ConsoleServerConnectionProfile, seq num: 10, local addr: xx.xx.193.9

      access-list outside_cryptomap_eventrack extended permit ip xx.xx.66.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 
      local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (xx.xx.66.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
      remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
      current_peer: xx.xx.xx.xx


      #pkts encaps: 16684, #pkts encrypt: 16684, #pkts digest: 16684
      #pkts decaps: 16834, #pkts decrypt: 16834, #pkts verify: 16834
      #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
      #pkts not compressed: 16684, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
      #pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
      #PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
      #TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
      #Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
      #pkts no sa (send): 0, #pkts invalid sa (rcv): 0
      #pkts encaps failed (send): 0, #pkts decaps failed (rcv): 0
      #pkts invalid prot (rcv): 0, #pkts verify failed: 0
      #pkts invalid identity (rcv): 0, #pkts invalid len (rcv): 0
      #pkts invalid pad (rcv): 0,
      #pkts invalid ip version (rcv): 0,
      #pkts replay rollover (send): 0, #pkts replay rollover (rcv): 0
      #pkts replay failed (rcv): 0
      #pkts min mtu frag failed (send): 0, #pkts bad frag offset (rcv): 0
      #pkts internal err (send): 0, #pkts internal err (rcv): 0

      local crypto endpt.: xx.xx.193.9/500, remote crypto endpt.: xx.xx.222.246/500
      path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 94(44), media mtu 1500
      PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: copy-df
      ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
      current outbound spi: 50D61913
      current inbound spi : 1BA74E8D

    inbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x1BA74E8D (463949453)
         transform: esp-aes-256 esp-sha-512-hmac no compression 
         in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, PFS Group 14, IKEv2, }
         slot: 0, conn_id: 49152, crypto-map: ConsoleServerConnectionProfile
         sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4146528/1834)
         IV size: 16 bytes
         replay detection support: Y
         Anti replay bitmap: 
          0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFFFF
    outbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x50D61913 (1356208403)
         transform: esp-aes-256 esp-sha-512-hmac no compression 
         in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, PFS Group 14, IKEv2, }
         slot: 0, conn_id: 49152, crypto-map: ConsoleServerConnectionProfile
         sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4192686/1834)
         IV size: 16 bytes
         replay detection support: Y
         Anti replay bitmap: 
          0x00000000 0x00000001
```

From the router's perspective, `show crypto ipsec sa detail`:

```
interface: GigabitEthernet0/0
    Crypto map tag: FlexVPN, local addr xx.xx.222.246

   protected vrf: (none)
   local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (xx.xx.66.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
   current_peer xx.xx.193.9 port 500
     PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,}
    #pkts encaps: 18179, #pkts encrypt: 18179, #pkts digest: 18179
    #pkts decaps: 18024, #pkts decrypt: 18024, #pkts verify: 18024
    #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
    #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
    #pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
    #pkts no sa (send) 0, #pkts invalid sa (rcv) 0
    #pkts encaps failed (send) 0, #pkts decaps failed (rcv) 0
    #pkts invalid prot (recv) 0, #pkts verify failed: 0
    #pkts invalid identity (recv) 0, #pkts invalid len (rcv) 0
    #pkts replay rollover (send): 0, #pkts replay rollover (rcv) 0
    ##pkts replay failed (rcv): 0
    #pkts tagged (send): 0, #pkts untagged (rcv): 0
    #pkts not tagged (send): 0, #pkts not untagged (rcv): 0
    #pkts internal err (send): 0, #pkts internal err (recv) 0

     local crypto endpt.: xx.xx.222.246, remote crypto endpt.: xx.xx.193.9
     plaintext mtu 1422, path mtu 1500, ip mtu 1500, ip mtu idb GigabitEthernet0/0
     current outbound spi: 0x1BA74E8D(463949453)
     PFS (Y/N): Y, DH group: group14

     inbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x50D61913(1356208403)
        transform: esp-256-aes esp-sha512-hmac ,
        in use settings ={Tunnel, }
        conn id: 2015, flow_id: Onboard VPN:15, sibling_flags 80000040, crypto map: FlexVPN
        sa timing: remaining key lifetime (k/sec): (4166728/1692)
        IV size: 16 bytes
        replay detection support: Y
        Status: ACTIVE(ACTIVE)

     inbound ah sas:

     inbound pcp sas:

     outbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x1BA74E8D(463949453)
        transform: esp-256-aes esp-sha512-hmac ,
        in use settings ={Tunnel, }
        conn id: 2016, flow_id: Onboard VPN:16, sibling_flags 80000040, crypto map: FlexVPN
        sa timing: remaining key lifetime (k/sec): (4166663/1692)
        IV size: 16 bytes
        replay detection support: Y
        Status: ACTIVE(ACTIVE)

     outbound ah sas:

     outbound pcp sas:

   protected vrf: (none)
   local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.255.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
   current_peer xx.xx.193.9 port 500
     PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,}
    #pkts encaps: 8, #pkts encrypt: 8, #pkts digest: 8
    #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
    #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
    #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
    #pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
    #pkts no sa (send) 0, #pkts invalid sa (rcv) 0
    #pkts encaps failed (send) 0, #pkts decaps failed (rcv) 0
    #pkts invalid prot (recv) 0, #pkts verify failed: 0
    #pkts invalid identity (recv) 0, #pkts invalid len (rcv) 0
    #pkts replay rollover (send): 0, #pkts replay rollover (rcv) 0
    ##pkts replay failed (rcv): 0
    #pkts tagged (send): 0, #pkts untagged (rcv): 0
    #pkts not tagged (send): 0, #pkts not untagged (rcv): 0
    #pkts internal err (send): 0, #pkts internal err (recv) 0

     local crypto endpt.: xx.xx.222.246, remote crypto endpt.: xx.xx.193.9
     plaintext mtu 1422, path mtu 1500, ip mtu 1500, ip mtu idb GigabitEthernet0/0
     current outbound spi: 0x0(0)
     PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none

     inbound esp sas:

     inbound ah sas:

     inbound pcp sas:

     outbound esp sas:

     outbound ah sas:

     outbound pcp sas:
```

Intersting to see that the router shows two SAs, despite one of them being down, while the ASA shows only once.

**Bringing up the SA**

I can bring up the SA from the router:

```
mobilerack1-rtr#ping 192.168.255.10 source vlan 10
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.255.10, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 192.168.10.254 

Jun 27 14:57:54.863: [ACL FlexVPN]: state = ACL notify RP action 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: IPSEC:(SESSION ID = 2) (STATES) SADB_ROOT_SM (sadb_root_process_kmi_message) called static seqno 10 dynamic seqno 0
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [ACL FlexVPN]: state = ACL KMI create SA for PtoP 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [KMI Forward]: state = KMI Initializing 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [KMI Forward]: state = change priority 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [KMI Forward]: state = forward 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Check. redundant request 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Allocate Session 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Session]: state = Session Initialization 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Insert Peer 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Allocate Sibling 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Sibling]: state = Sibling Initialization 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Create In/Outbound SAs 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Ident Set Replay 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Ident 80000008]: state = Send SAs to sibling and install them 
Jun 27 14:57:55.163: [Sibling]: state = Hook Session 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Session]: state = Add Sibling to Session List 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Sibling]: state = Fill Sibling with CE data 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Sibling 52EE23C6]: state = Hook SA Struct to Sibling 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Sibling 52EE23C6]: state = Install SPI 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Sibling 52EE23C6]: state = Del Transient SPI 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Check. Outbound Enable Status 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Got Enable Outbound SA 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Select Outbound SA 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Install New Outbound SA 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Set flow_installed 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: IPSEC:(SESSION ID = 2) (STATES) ident_set_flow_installed_action Sending crypto_ss_connection_open

Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Check Install SA Declare Success 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [Ident 80000008]: state = Declare success 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [KMI Forward]: state = success 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [KMI Forward]: deleting state machine 
Jun 27 14:57:55.167: [ACL FlexVPN]: state = ACL KMI check result ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a dynamic cryptomap, traffic must be initiated from your router. Using IP-SLA you could schedule an ICMP operation from your VLAN10 interface to the anyconnect ip range that is scheduled to run in a defined time interval.

IP SLA Config Guide:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/ip_sla/configuration/guide/hsla_c/hsicmp.html

Let me know if you need a config example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am aware that the initial tunnel must be initiated from the router. The IKE Phase 1 has completed and the tunnel is basically there. The question is: does this also hold true for child SAs? In this moment I have the phase I tunnel, so why can't the ASA initiate the second child SA with the phase I tunnel in place? And yes, IP SLA is the workaround I have currently implemented, which for sure works.

Comment: Unfortunetly it is not supported to initiate P2 to the dynamic peer. Theoretically it should be possible since the ASA knows the DST IP from P1 but according to cisco documentation the dynamic peer must establish the session. I have tested this scenario in the lab and can confirm that it is indeed not working.

Reference:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/112075-dynamic-ipsec-asa-router-ccp.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the linked document I only find this sentence: "he IPsec tunnel establishes when the tunnel is initiated from the Router end only. ASA could not initiate a VPN tunnel because of the dynamic IPsec configuration.". Where do you get the information from that the P2 establishment of a child SA is not supported from the static endpoint towards the dynamic endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic IPsec Tunnel Between a Statically Addressed ASA and a Dynamically Addressed Cisco IOS Router that uses CCP Configuration Example](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/112075-dynamic-ipsec-asa-router-ccp.html)

This configuration enables the PIX Security Appliance to create a dynamic IPsec LAN-to-LAN (L2L) tunnel with a remote VPN router. This router dynamically receive its outside public IP address from its Internet service provider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I do not want to offend you, but have you actually read the problem above? The tunnel is configured and it actually works, there is just one limitation I'm not sure about. The Phase 1 tunnel is established and phase 2 also works for one SA, but not for a second SA that is initiated by the central ASA.

Comment: With EZVPN there is a client and a server.  Which is the ASA, the server or client?